# Make multi Method / Function useage

Tags: java

I'm making an API and I want to use

```
sendMessage.BroadCast().Red().Group(String group, String MSG);
```

How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

It's called Fluent Interface. Google it and you'll find descriptions and tutorials how to design one in Java. Here are two links to help you get started:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

https://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/

Comment: Can you explane it to me?

Comment: Got it Thank you so much!